# C casting char ** to char *[]

Tags: c, linux

I am trying to run shell command from a C program.

I have a command structure:

```
struct Command {
    char * builtInCommand;
    char ** args;
    int argSize;
    //...
}typedef command;
```

`builtInCommand` represents built-in shell commands like `pwd`, `ls`.

I can't run [execv](https://linux.die.net/man/3/execv) function with `args`
Actually, `args` represents a char * [].

This is working:

```
execl(src, c->builtInCommand, c->args[0], c->args[1], c->args[2], NULL);
```

But this is not:

```
execv(src, c->args);
```

I don't know how many arguments do I have so I want to use `c->args` approach.

Here is the full code:

```
void runBuiltIn(command * c) {

    char src[strlen(c->builtInCommand) + strlen("/bin/")];
    strcpy(src,  "/bin/");
    strcat(src, c->builtInCommand);

    /*Spawn a child to run the program.*/
    pid_t pid=fork();
    if (pid==0) { /* child process */
        execv(src, c->args);
        exit(127); /* only if execv fails */
    }
    else { /* pid!=0; parent process */
        waitpid(pid,0,0); /* wait for child to exit */
    }
}
```

If I put 2 argument to `args` it print the result according to the second arg and bypassing first array element.

Why execv function is not passing my args correctly to shell command?

---

***Outputs***:

**Case 1**: `execl(src, c->builtInCommand, c->args[0], c->args[1], c->args[2], NULL);`

```
>ls
CMakeCache.txt  CMakeFiles  cmake_install.cmake  Makefile  Shell  Shell.cbp
>ls -a
.   CMakeCache.txt  cmake_install.cmake  Shell
..  CMakeFiles      Makefile         Shell.cbp
>ls -a -l
total 72
drwxrwxr-x 3 md7zn4 md7zn4  4096 Nov 28 02:29 .
drwxrwxr-x 8 md7zn4 md7zn4  4096 Nov 26 00:28 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 md7zn4 md7zn4 19444 Nov 24 21:46 CMakeCache.txt
drwxrwxr-x 5 md7zn4 md7zn4  4096 Nov 28 02:29 CMakeFiles
-rw-rw-r-- 1 md7zn4 md7zn4  1553 Nov 24 21:46 cmake_install.cmake
-rw-rw-r-- 1 md7zn4 md7zn4  6467 Nov 26 00:28 Makefile
-rwxrwxr-x 1 md7zn4 md7zn4 19856 Nov 28 02:29 Shell
-rw-rw-r-- 1 md7zn4 md7zn4  6060 Nov 26 00:28 Shell.cbp
```

**Case 2:** `execv(src, c->args)`

```
>ls
A NULL argv[0] was passed through an exec system call.
>ls -a
CMakeCache.txt  CMakeFiles  cmake_install.cmake  Makefile  Shell  Shell.cbp
>ls -l -a
.   CMakeCache.txt  cmake_install.cmake  Shell
..  CMakeFiles      Makefile         Shell.cbp
>ls -a -l
total 64
-rw-rw-r-- 1 md7zn4 md7zn4 19444 Nov 24 21:46 CMakeCache.txt
drwxrwxr-x 5 md7zn4 md7zn4  4096 Nov 28 02:33 CMakeFiles
-rw-rw-r-- 1 md7zn4 md7zn4  1553 Nov 24 21:46 cmake_install.cmake
-rw-rw-r-- 1 md7zn4 md7zn4  6467 Nov 26 00:28 Makefile
-rwxrwxr-x 1 md7zn4 md7zn4 19848 Nov 28 02:33 Shell
-rw-rw-r-- 1 md7zn4 md7zn4  6060 Nov 26 00:28 Shell.cbp
```

Simply I want the output of case 1, with the code of case 2 :)

Comment: Your `strcat` causes a buffer overflow, you did not allocate space for the null terminator.  Maybe you also forgot to null-terminate `c->args`

Comment: If you are still having trouble please post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @M.M should I write my output for both cases?

Comment: Sure (in addition to the MCVE)

Comment: @M.M Actually I didn't sense any trouble with `strcat´ because it worked with execl

Comment: It's still a mistake even if it seemed to work in some circumstance

Comment: @M.M What should I do with strcat, what about this:    char * src = malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(c->builtInCommand) + strlen("/bin/") + 1);

Comment: Just keep it as you have but add `+1` to the dimension

Comment: Oh, sorry :) I got it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184359/discussion-between-muhammed-ozdogan-and-m-m).

Comment: You need to post a MCVE, then people will be able to answer your question.

Comment: Also it looks like you did not put `builtInCommand` as `args[0]` which is required by `execv`

Comment: Thank you very much you solved the problem, yes intentionally, I had removed builtInCommand from args array, it was the mistake.